# NRPE error: WARNING: my_system() seteuid(0): Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, nrpe

I'm running a probe with no arguments with NRPE v4.0.3 on a RHEL7.9 remote server. I keep getting error:

> NRPE: Unable to read output

. When I run:

sudo journalctl -u nrpe --since "1 hour ago"
on the remote server, I always get the same error:

> WARNING: my_system() seteuid(0): Operation not permitted

.

I parsed a few topics regarding that last error, but none seems to address my issue. Here is the most valuable insight on this issue: On more than a dozen other RHEL servers (6.9, 6.10, 7.9) with the same NRPE version, the same code executed with NRPE works perfectly. I keep trying to figure out which configuration box I didn't ticked, because the error clearly doesn't seem to come out of the code. Could you please review my issue?

I tried to overlook the whole NRPE: configuration:

- Check NRPE version on all machines: always one and the same
- Check the different configuration files: even copying 'right' nrpe.cfg file didnt' resolve issue.
- Try setting a sudo call inside NRPE and creating an nrpe exception in the sudoers file didn't either